# encodeURI and Ext.urlDecode

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a page that loads some other page in an iframe via ExtJS:

```
alert(UNID); // returns  ...AAA==
...
    autoEl:{
        tag:"iframe",
        src: someurl+'?anyparam=anything&unid='+encodeURI(UNID)+'&someparam='
        // Chrome Console (Network tab) tells me the URI is ...AAA==&someparam=
    }
```

and the other web site uses ExtJS to decode the given params.

```
var params = Ext.urlDecode(window.location.search);
alert(params.unid); // returns ...AAA
```

Where is my error? If there is none, is this a bug in encodeURI or urlDecode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it's not a bug, `encodeURI` is not encoding the equals `=` symbol so when `Ext.urlDecode` parses the string it treats it as part of the *URI* - `...AAA = ''` and `'' = '' // useless / discarded`.

The answer is simply to use the correct function when encoding a *"component"* part of the *URI:*

```js
encodeURI('...AAA==');           // "...AAA=="
encodeURIComponent('...AAA==');  // "...AAA%3D%3D"
```

The differences are detailed in the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI).